# EJB + WebService on GlassFish with Netbeans enabling HTTPS

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I have to enable HTTPS for webservice which is inside EJB application. My environment is Netbeans 7.2 + GlassFish 3.1.2.2 OpenSource Server. In EAR project there is no WebApplication, so I try to add glassfish-ejb-jar.xml file with tag transport-guarantee with parameter CONFIDENTIAL, but application is still deploying into 8080 port, which is just unsecured port. Every solution I found has got only information about adding above into .xml file. Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's glassfish's setup, so you should set port in application server's configuration. You can do it in next way:
You can change port manually in `domain.xml` file

```
  <network-listener port="8282" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
  <network-listener port="8181" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
  <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
```

Or you can do it, using admin tool `asadmin`
[change port number with **asadmin** tool](https://blogs.oracle.com/openroad/entry/changing_default_glassfish_port_numbers)

Comment: After changes the only difference is that Netbeans is deploying into 8282 port, but still not into secured 8181 port.

Comment: Some other idea? Additionaly I created other ws client (via Netbeans wizard) and tried to configure it in the same way as in first post, but unfortunately it's still unsecured and port still didn't change to 8181.